# What does this mean abstract Class<TabFragment> getTabFragmentClass();?

Tags: java

What does the following abstract method mean and how to instantiate an object of a such type?

```
abstract Class<TabFragment> getTabFragmentClass();
```

Comment: `TabFragment fragment = getTabFragmentClass().newInstance()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an abstract method whose implementation should return a [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object representing `TabFragment`. There should only ever be one such object in existence, namely `TabFragment.class` (i.e. there is only *one* `Class` instance representing each class).

For example, you can override the method as such:

```
@Override
Class<TabFragment> getTabFragmentClass() {
    return TabFragment.class;
}
```

---

If you want to be able to return `Class` instances that represent subclasses of `TabFragment`, you can use

```
abstract Class<? extends TabFragment> getTabFragmentClass();
```

Comment: I need to return different classes from here, which derived from TabFragment, this is not possible right?

Comment: Actually it is possible. :) Apply the code from the answer above, and return a subclass.

Comment: It looks like a hack, isn't it? :)

Comment: @siik Absolutely not; it's perfectly reasonable.